# How to change meld theme?

Tags: meld

I've installed meld 3.18.0 from apt and it has very strange text highlighting for dark theme, I can barely see anything. How do I change it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo apt-get install dconf-editor -y`

Then in
`dconf-editor` :
`/org/gnome/meld`/
`style-schema`/
`Custom value = meld-dark`

[image]